# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Audio-Classification/wavefiles/b1'

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning

I am working over Audio Classification using deep learning and I am following a video series and stuck over one phase.
The below code is the written code in spyder:

```
import os

from tqdm import tqdm

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.io import wavfile

import python_speech_features

from python_speech_features import mfcc,logfbank

import librosa

def plot_signals(signals):

   fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, sharex=False,
                         aharey=True, figsize=(20,5))
   fig.suptitle('Time Series', size=16)
   i=0
   for x in range(2):
      for y in range(5):
        axes[x,y].set_title(list(signals.keys())[i])
        axes[x.y].plot(list(signals.value())[i])
        axes[x,y].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        axes[x,y].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        i+=1

def plot_fft(fft):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, sharex=False,
                         sharey=True, figsize=(20,5))
    fig.suptitle('Fourier Transform', size=16)
    i = 0
    for x in range(2):
       for y in range(5):
          data=list(fft.value())[i]
          Y, freq = data[0], data[1]
          axes[x,y].set_title(list(fft.keys())[i])
          axes[x.y].plot(freq, Y)
          axes[x,y].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
          axes[x,y].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
          i+=1

  def plot_fbank(fbank):
     fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, sharex=False,
                         sharey=True, figsize=(20,5))
     fig.suptitle('Filter Bank Coefficients', size = 16)
     i = 0
     for x in range(2):
        for y in range(5):
          axes[x,y].set_title(list(fbank.keys())[i])
          axes[x.y].imshow(list(fbank.values())[i],
            cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
          axes[x,y].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
          axes[x,y].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
          i+=1
        
    def plot_mfccs(mfccs):
         fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, sharex=False,
                         sharey=True, figsize=(20,5))
        fig.suptitle('Mel Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients', size=16)
        i = 0
       for x in range(2):
         for y in range(5):
           axes[x,y].set_title(list(mfcc.keys())[i])
           axes[x.y].imshow(list(mfccs.values())[i],
            cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
           axes[x,y].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
          axes[x,y].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
           i+=1

  df = pd.read_csv('cry.csv')
  df.set_index('fname', inplace=True)

     for f in df.index:
      samplerate, signal = wavfile.read('Audio-Classification/wavefiles/' + f)
      df.at[f, 'length'] = signal.shape[0]/samplerate

     classes = list(np.unique(df.label))
     class_dist = df.groupby(['label'])['length'].mean()
```

The error it is showing:

```
   runfile('C:/Users/atalp/Desktop/Audio-Classification/eda.py', wdir='C:/Users/atalp/Desktop/Audio-Classification')
   Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-0f3a8250d6ff>", line 1, in <module>
   runfile('C:/Users/atalp/Desktop/Audio-Classification/eda.py', wdir='C:/Users/atalp/Desktop/Audio-Classification')

  File "C:\Users\atalp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

 File "C:\Users\atalp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
  exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

 File "C:/Users/atalp/Desktop/Audio-Classification/eda.py", line 71, in <module>
   samplerate, signal = wavfile.read('Audio-Classification/wavefiles/' + f)

File "C:\Users\atalp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 233, in read
  fid = open(filename, 'rb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Audio-Classification/wavefiles/b1'
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s just that your file directory is not set right.

It seems like your `wdir = 'C:/Users/atalp/Desktop/Audio-Classification'`.

So the read file line should be like `wavfile.read('wavefiles/' + f)` instead of `wavfile.read('Audio-Classification/wavefiles/' + f)`.